# How do I stop images or flash from loading into the browser?

Tags: html, image, rendering

I am creating a web page that accepts a hyperlink from the user and displays that page in an iframe. While rendering the page, I would like to show just the text and simple colors, thats it.

I would like to block all the media files like images and flash scripts from showing up.

If not an extensive one, for the starters, I would like to confine the scope to .gif, .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .swf.

Or does anyone know of a site with similar functionality?

Comment: My understanding is that you can only change attributes of the iframe itself like `height` or `width` but you cannot actually access the DOM that is inside an iframe.

Comment: Will the urls be on the same domain as the site? If so, a simple javascript function could access the iframe and remove media. If _not_ you will not be able to affect the content in anyway due to [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) security policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple dom parser and parse the page before show it in iframe. Then before showing it you can remove whatever you want.

your iframe whould like

```
<iframe src="your_parser.php"></iframe>
```

In your parser you can get the content from page using file_get_contents() or curl() it is your choise (i would use curl). Then you can remove the media you want.

Comment: Would Micheal's comment apply here for your solution?

Comment: Not at all. This solution modifies the html content after it was got from the other domain. Michaels solution will works only for same domain and the iframe content is changed after loading. My solution is to get the target domain content from your server, modify it and then show it modified.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox, use the Adblock Plus extension. You can specify the types of items to block via a filter rule. An example (using Safaribooks) looks like this:

```
||techbus.safaribooksonline.com/static/201109-2191-techbus/images/6.0/*.jpg
```

However, if you're talking about incorporating functionality into your page to strip out a specific list of content-types, this approach wouldn't help you. You'd need to pull the html source and strip out the offending content-types.

Answer (score 0):

also if you are using cms. you should be turn off bbcode image, and embed html